# Set a Label text in 1st winform page to display on 2nd form page

Tags: c#

Im fairly new to C# so please forgive me if my terminology isn't to par. In my winform application I want to grab a name from a MySQL database @ login and display the name on a second page(home.cs). Im currently getting an error which is "An Object Reference is required for the non static field. In login.cs im trying to add something like -> `Home.bunifuCustomLabel2.Text = "test";` to set the label in home.cs basically... Login.cs is my 1st loading page and Home.cs is my 2nd page which loads after successful login. I would like to query the database while the connection is open and eventually set the label text for home.cs to display something like `Welcome, Name`

LOGIN.CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Firemax
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=xyz.com;port=3333;Initial Catalog = test_db;User Id = fml;password=imscrewed");
        int i;
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void BunifuMaterialTextbox1_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BunifuMaterialTextbox2_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bunifuMaterialTextbox2.isPassword = true;
        }

        private void BunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from users where username='" + bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "' and password='" + bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

            if (i==0)
            {
                bunifuCustomLabel3.Text = "You have entered either a wrong Username and/or Password";

                Home.bunifuCustomLabel2.Text = "test";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Hide();
                Home fm = new Home();
                fm.Show();
                fm.Location = this.Location;
            }
            con.Close();

        }

        private void BunifuMaterialTextbox1_OnValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

HOME.CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Firemax
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void BunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query has potential SQL injection issue, use `SqlParamemter` instead of string concatenation to provide string parameters.

Comment: Yes, totally agree! That will be on my list of next steps to refactor a lot of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to C# world! Changing code of logic.cs to following will eliminate the problem you are facing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Firemax
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=xyz.com;port=3333;Initial Catalog = test_db;User Id = fml;password=imscrewed");
        int i;
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void BunifuMaterialTextbox1_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BunifuMaterialTextbox2_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bunifuMaterialTextbox2.isPassword = true;
        }

        private void BunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from users where username='" + bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "' and password='" + bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

            Home fm = new Home();
            if (i==0)
            {
                bunifuCustomLabel3.Text = "You have entered either a wrong Username and/or Password";

                fm.bunifuCustomLabel2.Text = "test";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Hide();                
                fm.Show();
                fm.Location = this.Location;
            }
            con.Close();

        }

        private void BunifuMaterialTextbox1_OnValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Your code needs improvements. I would highly recommend investing 70 minutes in [C# video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfkTfcpWqAY&list=PLTjRvDozrdlz3_FPXwb6lX_HoGXa09Yef) by Mosh.

Comment: I had to make a quick modification because the label wasn't populating, So I moved ```fm.bunifuCustomLabel2.Text = "test";``` out of the if statement and placed it underneath ```Home fm = new Home();``` and its all working properly now thank you very much and for the video link I will be watching it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this  can help you

In your first activity

```
public static string myText= "";

myText=myLabel.Text;
```

In your second activity `Form_Load`

```
seconLabel.Text = Form3.myText;
```